# In Linux/ubuntu hardy Apache2, how do I find where my default access logs and error logs are being kept?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, unix, logging

I just installed Apache2 on my unix via aptitude.  Where are the default logs kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be in `/var/log/apache2/`.

You can change the default path by editing `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` :

For example :

> ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log